# passed or passed by

Tags: grammar, word-usage, prepositions

**Beautiful indeed is the path through which he passed.**


Is this sentence complete? Or, should I end the sentence with a "by" next to passed?
It does sound okay without "by" to me; but, I am not sure if it is grammatically correct.

Comment: You walk down a path. You don't walk through a path.

Comment: @Lambie You can however, pass _along_ a path. That might work.

Comment: @BoldBen One thing is what works in really unusual circumstances and another is communicating a base meaning to a learner....If a learner does not know walk down/up a path, I would start there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you can't add "by" to this sentence, grammatically, is that you already have a preposition ("through"), so adding on "by" creates a mix-up — you can't *pass by through something*. If "by" is what you want, then you should say: "Beautiful indeed is the path by which he passed".

You *could* also say *"beautiful indeed is the path which he passed by"* — but this would create a dangling preposition. Some grammar authorities consider this a terrible crime, while others shrug it off as common practice.

Moreover, your meaning changes with "by". The reader could think you mean that there was a beautiful path that he did *not* go down; instead, he passed by it and went somewhere else. That doesn't seem to be your intent.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Yes, my intent is to say that he did take that path. So, I guess the sentence is correct as such without any modification.

Comment: What do you think about the comment by Lambie? Is "pass through" not an acceptable usage?

Comment: @Ammu To my American ears, "pass through a path" sounds unusual when referring to a person — although I wouldn't say it's unacceptable. It would be more natural to say "the path he went down", "the path he walked along", "the path he followed".

And there's nothing wrong with "pass through" on its own. "He passed through a gate", "he passed through a forest" are fine.

To generalize a bit... I'd say "pass through" works best when the subject is _crossing an object_ from one side to another. _Paths_, however, are _followed_, so a wording in that style feels smoother.

Comment: One more note: "pass through" is also perfectly good if the subject _is_ a path (or pathlike thing). "The route passes through several cities", for example.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Andron. That helped a lot. You are good at explaining.

Comment: @Andron In the case of the route passing through the cities the route crosses the cities from side to side. The people following the route pass through the cities, but travel _along_ the path, not through it.